# What is the difference between user create Java API and Java jar?

Tags: jar, asp.net-web-api, java

I want to create web application that is having some functionality to be platform independent.For that i want to create Java API, but I am confused that is the same thing can be done using jar implementing that functionality?

Comment: Most of the time (if not always) when you create an API, it is in a jar (refer twitter API, facebook API, google API and so on).

Comment: please be more specific in your question, atm I cannot understand what you want to achieve or where you have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

That are two completely different things and cannot be compared as you did.

An **API** is an Application Programming Interface, so it defines the methods you can use. ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface))

A **JAR** is a Java Archive, it is just a packaged Java Application. ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_archive))

Comment: Just a packaged Java application which can be an interface for other application which wants to use functions/utilities of this packaged jar file. Am I correct?

Comment: @mvieghofer can you please edit your answer and answer more seriously? 7 years later you should know to provide a much better answer than that....

Answer (score 2):

An API, by definition, it's just an interface your application/library exposes to other applications to take advantage of your functionality. It doesn't impose any way of implementing it and there is no such a thing as a Java API (unless you mean you have multiple APIs for different programming languages in the form of wrappers). You can build your API just using a regular Java interface, and then pack that in a JAR other Java applications can import and use.

Answer (score -1):

A rest API written in Java will return a JSON payload which can then be read and used by an application written in any programming language. This is the advantage of web services.

A jar will return Java objects as a payload, so is optimal to use if you will be using it exclusively within other Java applications.